# C++ Atomic compare_exchange_weak

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Something happened when I used this feature that Was hard for me to understand
Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<atomic>
int main()
{
    std::atomic_size_t example;
    size_t expect = 1000;
    example.store(100, std::memory_order_release);
    //Now example.load() is 100;
    auto result = example.compare_exchange_weak(expect, 50, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    //Now result is zero(false) and example.load() is 100,I knew it would.
    result = example.compare_exchange_weak(expect, 50, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    //But now !!! result is One(true)! and example.load() is 50 Why???
}
```

What happens after the function is executed? Why are the two executions different?
I can't understand why this happened, so I really hope you can answer my question.Thank u very much.

I perfected this code, and now it compiles and executes properly, it's just a single thread.

Comment: Are there any other threads involved?

Comment: Those two `<< endl` things look like they don't belong.

Comment: Aside from the extraneous `<< endl`, this code won't compile. The first argument to `compare_exchange_weak` is passed by reference. You can't call it with a constant (1000); you have to have a **variable** of the appropriate type. If the comparison fails, the function **changes** the value of that variable to tell you what the atomic object held.

Comment: @user253751 Thank u , it's just a single thread. I just want to test this function.

Comment: @PeteBecker  I'm sorry, this is my negligence.I want to find out what happens after this function is executed. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: You need to **read the documentation** for [`compare_exchange_weak`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange).

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, I'll do it now And thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called an exchange for a reason.

Calling `example.compare_exchange_weak(expected, value);` roughly corresponds to the following piece of code done atomically:

```
if (expected==example){
    example = value;
    return true;
}
else
{
    expected = example;
    return false;
}
```

In your first call, the else branch is taken meaning `expected<-100` as 100 is the present value in `example` which is not altered.

The next call compares `example` to `expected` and they are obviously equal, so the if branch is taken. Thus `example==100` after the second call.

See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) for more detailed information.

This behavior is useful because you can always save the `expected` value somewhere safe and use a "burner" variable and this way you also get the currently stored value in `example`. Another way of looking at this: after the call `expected` will always contain the value stored in `example` before the call was made.

Comment: Yes!!!  thank you for your answer sincerely , I'm debugging this code, and you're right. really appreciate your patience.